# Pass file into jar

Tags: java, scala, maven, cassandra

I have jar file that contains this code

```
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Paths

import org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper

object CassandraMockBootable extends App {
  println("Running embedded Cassandra.........")
  val file = Paths.get("/target/classes/cassandra.yaml").toFile
  assert(file.exists())
  EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(file, 50000)
}
```

This jar is used in another application by a maven plugin that run a java process

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Embedded-Cassandra</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <name>Embedded-Cassandra</name>
              <skip>${skipStartService}</skip>
              <arguments>
                <argument>java</argument>
                <argument>-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argument>
                <argument>-Xss1M</argument>
                <argument>-XX:+UseParallelGC</argument>
                <argument>-cp</argument>
                <argument>../../mock-service/target/lib/*</argument>
                <argument>mocks.bootables.CassandraMockBootable</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I dont know how, but I've been unable to pass the `cassandra.yaml` to that process, and the assert never works.

I tried to put that file into the resources of src and test in the generated jar project, and the consumer project but nothing. The assert always fail.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using a relative path. Remove the first slash:

```scala
val file = Paths.get("target/classes/cassandra.yaml").toFile
```

Or, add a dot:

```scala
val file = Paths.get("./target/classes/cassandra.yaml").toFile
```

Or provide the full path

```scala
val file = Paths.get("/full/path/target/classes/cassandra.yaml").toFile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What still is not clear is, where I have to put the file. In the resource of the jar or in the resource of the project that use the jar. If you see my question, is running the jar in a maven plug-in inside another another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource folder and place yaml file in that, don't place in target folder path because target folder always gets refreshed when ever build happens this makes file to be unavailable.

So please create separate resource folder and keep yaml file, then try accessing

Comment: The resources files are copy into the target folder in every build of the maven module. Sorry but I dont understand, in which resource folder you mean?. The one of the jar project or the one that is consuming the jar?

Comment: In the jar project. The resources are usually in `src/main/resources`